# How to get rid of Syntax error near "or" in Verilog

Tags: syntax-error, task, verilog

I have recently started learning Verilog.
I am trying to build a `Full Adder` using `task`

```
task fullAdder(input a, b, c_in, output reg sum, c_out);
   reg x, y, z;
   begin
      halfAdder H1(x, y, a, b);
      halfAdder H2(sum, z, c_in, x);
      or M3(c_out, y, z);
   end
endtask

task halfAdder(input a, b, output sum, c_out);
   xor M1(sum, a, b);
   and M2(c_out, a, b);
endtask
```

I don't know what is wrong in my code, but it is giving errors like:

```
Syntax error near "or".
Syntax error near "xor".
Syntax error near "and".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not place instances inside a `task`; they should be in a `module` instead.  Also, you should remove the `reg` type from the `output` ports, and change the internal `reg` to `wire`:

```
module fullAdder(input a, b, c_in, output sum, c_out);
   wire x, y, z;
   begin
      halfAdder H1(x, y, a, b);
      halfAdder H2(sum, z, c_in, x);
      or M3(c_out, y, z);
   end
endmodule

module halfAdder(input a, b, output sum, c_out);
   xor M1(sum, a, b);
   and M2(c_out, a, b);
endmodule
```

You can open up a free account on edaplayground, where you will have access to simulators which give you more specific information about your syntax errors.